# How to parse Apache logs using a regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split this string in PHP:

```
11.11.11.11 - - [25/Jan/2000:14:00:01 +0100] "GET /1986.js HTTP/1.1" 200 932 "http://domain.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 GTB6"
```

How can split this into IP, date, HTTP method, domain-name and browser?

Comment: This is a worse version of this question, which goes into full parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603017/parse-apache-log-in-php-using-preg-match

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This log format seems to be the [Apache’s combined log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#combined). Try this regular expression:

```
/^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \[([^\]]+)\] "([A-Z]+)[^"]*" \d+ \d+ "[^"]*" "([^"]*)"$/m
```

The matching groups are as follows:

1. remote IP address
2. request date
3. request HTTP method
4. [*User-Agent*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) value

But the domain is not listed there. The second quoted string is the [*Referer*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) value.

Comment: @streetparade: Use `preg_match_all` and you get all matches: `preg_match_all('…', $str, $matches)`

Comment: well this regex doesnt compile... theres a round bracket missing ;)

Comment: This one is wrong, the auth-user field (3rd one, %u) can contain spaces.

Comment: @JulienPalard Would you mind providing an update proposal?

Comment: @Gumbo Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603017/parse-apache-log-in-php-using-preg-match

Comment: This regex doesn't match urls or referers with escaped double quotes: \".  Maybe use "([^"]|\\")*" instead of "[^"]*"
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352140/2496827

Answer (score 4):

You should check out a regular expression tutorial. But here is the answer:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \[(.*?)\] "(\S+).*?" \d+ \d+ "(.*?)" "(.*?)"/', $line, $m)) {
  $ip = $m[1];
  $date = $m[2];
  $method = $m[3];
  $referer = $m[4];
  $browser = $m[5];
}
```

Take care, it's not the domain name in the log but the HTTP referer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some Perl, not PHP, but the regex to use is the same. This regex works to parse everything I've seen; clients can send some bizarre requests:

```
my ($ip, $date, $method, $url, $protocol, $alt_url, $code, $bytes,
        $referrer, $ua) = (m/
    ^(\S+)\s                    # IP
    \S+\s+                      # remote logname
    (?:\S+\s+)+                 # remote user
    \[([^]]+)\]\s               # date
    "(\S*)\s?                   # method
    (?:((?:[^"]*(?:\\")?)*)\s   # URL
    ([^"]*)"\s|                 # protocol
    ((?:[^"]*(?:\\")?)*)"\s)    # or, possibly URL with no protocol
    (\S+)\s                     # status code
    (\S+)\s                     # bytes
    "((?:[^"]*(?:\\")?)*)"\s    # referrer
    "(.*)"$                     # user agent
/x);
die "Couldn't match $_" unless $ip;
$alt_url ||= '';
$url ||= $alt_url;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// # Parses the NCSA Combined Log Format lines:
$pattern = '/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (\[[^\]]+\]) "(.*) (.*) (.*)" ([0-9\-]+) ([0-9\-]+) "(.*)" "(.*)"$/';
```

Usage:

```
if (preg_match($pattern,$yourstuff,$matches)) {

    //# puts each part of the match in a named variable

    list($whole_match, $remote_host, $logname, $user, $date_time, $method, $request, $protocol, $status, $bytes, $referer, $user_agent) = $matches;

}
```