# java parse log file

Tags: java, apache, logging

I am trying to parse the apache log file which is logging in this format

```
LogFormat "%t %u [%D %h %{True-Client-IP}i %{UNIQUE_ID}e %r] %{Cookie}i %s \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{host}i\" %l %b %{Referer}i"
```

below is the code I am testing with...

```
import java.util.regex.*;


interface LogExample {
    /** The number of fields that must be found. */
    public static final int NUM_FIELDS = 11;

    /** The sample log entry to be parsed. */
    public static final //String logEntryLine = "123.45.67.89 - - [27/Oct/2000:09:27:09 -0400] \"GET /java/javaResources.html HTTP/1.0\" 200 10450 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.6 [en] (X11; U; OpenBSD 2.8 i386; Nav)\"";
    String logEntryLine = "[02/Dec/2013:14:10:30 -0000] - [52075 10.102.4.254 177.43.52.210 UpyU1gpmBAwAACfd5W0AAAAW GET /SS14-VTam-ny_019.jpg.rendition.zoomable.jpg HTTP/1.1] hsfirstvisit=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fen-us||1372268254000; _opt_vi_3FNG8DZU=F870DCFD-CBA4-4B6E-BB58-4605A78EE71A; __ptca=145721067.0aDxsZlIuM48.1372279055.1379945057.1379950362.9; __ptv_62vY4e=0aDxsZlIuM48; __pti_62vY4e=0aDxsZlIuM48; __ptcz=145721067.1372279055.1.0.ptmcsr=(direct)|ptmcmd=(none)|ptmccn=(direct); __hstc=145721067.b86362bb7a1d257bfa2d1fb77e128a85.1372268254968.1379934256743.1379939561848.9; hubspotutk=b86362bb7a1d257bfa2d1fb77e128a85; USER_GROUP=julinho%3Afalse; has_js=1; WT_FPC=id=177.43.52.210-1491335248.30301337:lv=1385997780893:ss=1385997780893; dtCookie=1F2E0E1037589799D8D503EB8CFA12A1|_default|1; RM=julinho%3A5248423ad3fe062f06c54915e6cde5cb45147977; wcid=UpyKsQpmBAwAABURyNoAAAAS%3A35d8227ba1e8a9a9cebaaf8d019a74777c32b4c8; Carte::KerberosLexicon_getWGSN=82ae3dcd1b956288c3c86bdbed6ebcc0fd040e1e; UserData=Username%3AJULINHO%3AHomepage%3A1%3AReReg%3A0%3ATrialist%3A0%3ALanguage%3Aen%3ACcode%3Abr%3AForceReReg%3A0; UserID=1356673%3A12345%3A1234567890%3A123%3Accode%3Abr; USER_DATA=1356673%3Ajulinho%3AJulio+Jose%3Ada+Silva%3Ajulinho%40tecnoblu.com.br%3A0%3A1%3Aen%3Abr%3A%3AWGSN%3A1385990833.81925%3A82ae3dcd1b956288c3c86bdbed6ebcc0fd040e1e; MODE=FONTIS; SECTION=%2Fcontent%2Fsection%2Fhome.html; edge_auth=ip%3D177.43.52.210~expires%3D1385994522~access%3D%2Fapps%2F%2A%21%2Fbin%2F%2A%21%2Fcontent%2F%2A%21%2Fetc%2F%2A%21%2Fhome%2F%2A%21%2Flibs%2F%2A%21%2Freport%2F%2A%21%2Fsection%2F%2A%21%2Fwgsn%2F%2A~md5%3D90e73ee10161c1afacab12c6ea30b4ef; __utma=94539802.1793276213.1372268248.1385572390.1385990581.16; __utmb=94539802.52.9.1385991739764; __utmc=94539802; __utmz=94539802.1372268248.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); WT_FPC=id=177.43.52.210-1491335248.30301337:lv=1386000374581:ss=1386000374581; dtPC=-; NSC_wtfswfs_xfcgbsn40-41=ffffffff096e1a1d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; akamai-edge=5ac6e5b3d0bbe2ea771bb2916d8bab34ea222a6a 200 \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36\" \"www.domain.com\" - 463952 http://www.domain.com/content/report/shows/New_York/KSHK/trip/s_s_14_ny_ww/sheers.html";

}

public class readLog implements LogExample {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        //String logEntryPattern = "^([\\d.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(.+?)\" (\\d{3}) (\\d+) \"([^\"]+)\" \"([^\"]+)\"";
        //String logEntryPattern = "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] (\\S+) \\[(\\d]+) ([\\d.]+) ([\\d.]+) (.+?)\\] (.*)";
        String logEntryPattern = "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] (.*)";

        System.out.println("Using RE Pattern:");
        System.out.println(logEntryPattern);

        System.out.println("Input line is:");
        System.out.println(logEntryLine);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logEntryPattern);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(logEntryLine);
        //if (!matcher.matches() ||
        //        NUM_FIELDS != matcher.groupCount()) {
        //    System.err.println("Bad log entry (or problem with RE?):");
        //    System.err.println(logEntryLine);
        //    return;
       // }
        System.out.println("Date&Time: " + matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println("Time taken to serve request: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Source IP: " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("Client IP: " + matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println("Unique ID: " + matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println("Request: " + matcher.group(5));
        System.out.println("Cookie: " + matcher.group(6));
        System.out.println("Request type: " + matcher.group(7));
        System.out.println("User agent: " + matcher.group(8));
        System.out.println("Remote logname: " + matcher.group(9));
        System.out.println("Size of response: " + matcher.group(10));
        System.out.println("Referrer: " + matcher.group(11));
    }
}
```

some example logs are:

```
[03/Dec/2013:10:53:59 +0000] - [32002 10.102.4.254 195.229.241.182 Up24RwpmBAwAAA1LWJsAAAAR GET /content/dam/Central_Library/Street_Shots/Youth/2012/09sep/LFW/Gallery_03/LFW_SS13_SEPT_12_777.jpg.image.W0N539E3452S3991w313.original.jpg HTTP/1.1] __utmc=94539802; dtCookie=EFD9D09B6A2E1789F1329FC1381A356A|_default|1; dtPC=471217988_141#_load_; Carte::KerberosLexicon_getdomain=6701c1320dd96688b2e40b92ce748eee7ae99722; UserData=Username%3ALSHARMA%3AHomepage%3A1%3AReReg%3A0%3ATrialist%3A0%3ALanguage%3Aen%3ACcode%3Aae%3AForceReReg%3A0; UserID=1375493%3A12345%3A1234567890%3A123%3Accode%3Aae; USER_DATA=1375493%3ALSharma%3ALokesh%3ASharma%3Alokesh.sharma%40landmarkgroup.com%3A0%3A1%3Aen%3Aae%3A%3Adomain%3A1386060868.51392%3A6701c1320dd96688b2e40b92ce748eee7ae99722; MODE=FONTIS; __utma=94539802.911097326.1339390457.1386060848.1386065609.190; __utmz=94539802.1384758205.177.38.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __kti=1339390460526,http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F,; __ktv=28e8-6c4-be3-ce54137d9e48271; WT_FPC=id=2.50.27.157-3067016480.30226245:lv=1386047044279:ss=1386046439530; _opt_vi_3FNG8DZU=42880957-D2F1-4DC5-AF16-FEF88891D24E; __hstc=145721067.750d315a49c64268192826b3911a4e5a.1351772962050.1381151113005.1381297633204.66; hsfirstvisit=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3Ddomain.com%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CB0QFjAA%26url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F%26ei%3DDmuSULW3AcTLhAfJ24CoDA%26usg%3DAFQjCNGvPmmyn8Bk67OUv-HwjVU4Ff3q1w|1351772962000; hubspotutk=750d315a49c64268192826b3911a4e5a; __ptca=145721067.jQ7lN5U3C4eN.1351758562.1381136713.1381283233.66; __ptv_62vY4e=jQ7lN5U3C4eN; __pti_62vY4e=jQ7lN5U3C4eN; __ptcz=145721067.1351758562.1.0.ptmcsr=google|ptmcmd=organic|ptmccn=(organic)|ptmctr=domain.com; RM=Lsharma%3Ac163b6097f90d2869e537f95900e1c464daa8fb9; wcid=Up2cRApmBAwAAFOiVhcAAAAH%3Af32e5e5f5b593175bfc71af082ab26e4055efeb6; __utmb=94539802.71.9.1386067462709; edge_auth=ip%3D195.229.241.182~expires%3D1386069280~access%3D%2Fapps%2F%2A%21%2Fbin%2F%2A%21%2Fcontent%2F%2A%21%2Fetc%2F%2A%21%2Fhome%2F%2A%21%2Flibs%2F%2A%21%2Freport%2F%2A%21%2Fsection%2F%2A%21%2Fdomain%2F%2A~md5%3D5b47f34172392487dcd44c1d837e2e54; has_js=1; SECTION=%2Fcontent%2Fsection%2Finspiration-design%2Fstreet-shots.html; JSESSIONID=b9377099-7708-45ae-b6e7-c575ffe82187; WT_FPC=id=2.50.27.157-3067016480.30226245:lv=1386053618209:ss=1386053618209; USER_GROUP=LSharma%3Afalse; NSC_wtfswfs_xfcgbsn40-41=ffffffff096e1a1d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" "www.domain.com" - 24516 http://www.domain.com/content/report/Street_Shots/Youth/Global_round_up/2013/01_Jan/mens_youth_stylingglobalround-up1.html
[03/Dec/2013:10:53:59 +0000] - [5998 10.102.4.254 165.193.178.71 Up24RwpmBAwAAH6zEtsAAAAB GET /content/dam/Central_Library/Catwalk_Shows/Paris/Spring_Summer_2013/Mens_foot/Comme_Des_Garcons/CDGarcons_FOOT_01201206291020.jpg.rendition.thumbnail.jpg HTTP/1.1] SECTION=%2Fcontent%2Fsection%2Fhome.html; USER_GROUP=anonymous%3Afalse; search_cookie=; searchtime_cookie=all; search_type=domain_photos; WT_FPC=id=46.65.238.194-75238752.30316538:lv=1386068091347:ss=1386066333452; NSC_wtfswfs_xfcgbsn40-41=ffffffff096e1a1d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; Carte::KerberosLexicon_getdomain=bb0da583303a49a8294403860ea3b4d326e6934d; UserData=Username%3AUARTSLONDON%3AHomepage%3A1%3AReReg%3A0%3ATrialist%3A0%3ALanguage%3Aen%3ACcode%3Agb%3AForceReReg%3A0; UserID=1264925%3A12345%3A1234567890%3A123%3Accode%3Agb; USER_DATA=1264925%3Auartslondon%3AUniversity%3Aof+the+Arts+London%3A%3A0%3A1%3Aen%3Agb%3AEDU%3Adomain%3A1386066044.0231%3Abb0da583303a49a8294403860ea3b4d326e6934d; MODE=FONTIS; edge_auth=ip%3D165.193.178.71~expires%3D1386067844~access%3D%2Fapps%2F%2A%21%2Fbin%2F%2A%21%2Fcontent%2F%2A%21%2Fetc%2F%2A%21%2Fhome%2F%2A%21%2Flibs%2F%2A%21%2Freport%2F%2A%21%2Fsection%2F%2A%21%2Fdomain%2F%2A~md5%3Dd1210aafdb5701c303c348f2fec1c3ff; dtCookie=6CF28DC8E50C0E5179365B4683DCB3D8|_default|1 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36" "www.domain.com" - 6068 http://www.domain.com/content/domain/unifiedsearch.html?q=comme%20des%20garcons&tags=&type=domain_photos&t=all&_charset_=utf-8
[03/Dec/2013:10:53:59 +0000] - [324 10.102.4.254 - Up24RwpmBAwAAHv627sAAAAQ GET /akamai-sureroute-test-object.htm HTTP/1.1] dtCookie=85A2D2D0984B2071B94E304F711146D1|_default|1 200 "FirstFlowAgent" "day-cms.domain.com.akadns.net" - 214 -
[03/Dec/2013:10:53:59 +0000] - [258 10.102.4.254 127.0.0.1 Up24RwpmBAwAAAl@3VUAAAAJ GET /akamai-sureroute-test-object.htm HTTP/1.1] dtCookie=1AD942993C377EC2C95223611ED38204|_default|1 200 "-" "secure.domain.com" - 215 -
```

any idea about the regex filters which I need for this logformat?

Comment: Where's the problem? You seem to have some patterns already, why don't you use those? You might want to read the file line by line and then apply the regex to each line but other than that, I don't see where you'd have difficulties.

Comment: Will the RegEx in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221636/regex-for-apache-logs-in-php) post not help?

Comment: OK, the filter i am applying should catch two groups, date and the rest , apprently that is failing..so was hoping i will catch with the rest of the words in the line slowly.....:)i am being bit lazy here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i managed to now split this...

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class stringRS {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String line = "[03/Dec/2013:10:53:59 +0000] - [32002 10.102.4.254 195.229.241.182 Up24RwpmBAwAAA1LWJsAAAAR GET /content/dam/original.jpg HTTP/1.1] __utmc=94539802; dtCookie=EFD9D09B6A2E1; dtPC=load_; Carte::Kertdomain=6701c1320dd99722; UserData=Username%3ALSHARMA%3AHomepageg%3A0; UserID=1375493%de%3Aae; USER_DATA=rma%40landmain%3A13860608699722; MODE=FONTIS; __utma=945326.5609.190; __utmz=94ic|utmcomain.com%2F,; __ktv=28e8-6c4-be3-ce54137d9e48271; WT_FPC=id=2.50480.30226245:lv=1386047044279:ss=1386046439530; _opt_vi_3FNG8DZU=42880957-D2F1-4DC5-AF16-FEF88891D24E; __hstc=145721067.750d315a49c64268192826b3911a4e5a.1351772962050.1381151113005.1381297633204.66; hsfirstvisit=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3Ddomain.com%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CB0QFjAA%26url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F%26ei%3DDmuSULW3AcTLhAfJ24CoDA%26usg%3DAFQjCNGvPmmyn8Bk67OUv-HwjVU4Ff3q1w|1351772962000; hubspotutk=750d315a49c64268192826b3911a4e5a; __ptca=145721067.jQ7lN5U3C4eN.1351758562.1381136713.1381283233.66; __ptv_62vY4e=jQ7lN5U3C4eN; __pti_62vY4e=jQ7lN5U3C4eN; __ptcz=145721067.1351758562.1.0.ptmcsr=google|ptmcmd=organic|ptmccn=(organic)|ptmctr=domain.com; RM=Lsharma%3Ac163b6097f90d2869e537f95900e1c464daa8fb9; wcid=Up2cRApmBAwAAFOiVhcAAAAH%3Af32e5e5f5b593175bfc71af082ab26e4055efeb6; __utmb=94539802.71.9.1386067462709; edge_auth=ip%3D195.229.241.182~expires%3D1386069280~access%3D%2Fapps%2F%2A%21%2Fbin%2F%2A%21%2Fcontent%2F%2A%21%2Fetc%2F%2A%21%2Fhome%2F%2A%21%2Flibs%2F%2A%21%2Freport%2F%2A%21%2Fsection%2F%2A%21%2Fdomain%2F%2A~md5%3D5b47f34172392487dcd44c1d837e2e54; has_js=1; SECTION=%2Fcontent%2Fsection%2Finspiration-design%2Fstreet-shots.html; JSESSIONID=b9377099-7708-45ae-b6e7-c575ffe82187; WT_FPC=id=2.50.27.157-3067016480.30226245:lv=1386053618209:ss=1386053618209; USER_GROUP=LSharma%3Afalse; NSC_wtfswfs_xfcgbsn40-41=ffffffff096e1a1d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660 200 \"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)\" \"www.domain.com\" - 24516 http://www.domain.com/content/report/Street_Shots/Youth/Global_round_up/2013/01_Jan/mens_youth_stylingglobalround-up1.html";

        String pattern = "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] (\\S) \\[(\\w+) ([\\d.]+) ([\\d.]+) (\\w+) (\\w+.*)\\] (\\w.*?\\d{3}) ([\\d.]+) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" (\\S) (\\w+) (.*)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("String: " + m.group(0) );
            System.out.println("Date&Time: " + m.group(1) );
            System.out.println("User: " + m.group(2) );
            System.out.println("Time taken: " + m.group(3) );
            System.out.println("Source IP: " + m.group(4) );
            System.out.println("Client IP: " + m.group(5) );
            System.out.println("Unique ID: " + m.group(6) );
            System.out.println("Reguest: " + m.group(7) );
            System.out.println("Cookie: " + m.group(8) );
            System.out.println("Request Type: " + m.group(9) );
            System.out.println("Browser: " + m.group(10) );
            System.out.println("Domain: " + m.group(11) );
            System.out.println("Remote logname: " + m.group(12) );
            System.out.println("bytes sent: " + m.group(13) );
            System.out.println("Referrer: " + m.group(14) );
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've similar log parse issue, this is almost the same log containgin additional IP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886786/parse-log-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem in the past one too many times. 
So I a few years go approached this problem so that the LogFormat specification is used as the schema to read the log files with. I fully automated the step from LogFormat to 'regex'.

https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser

I did a quick test with your case.

First I defined this:

```
public class MyRecord {
    @Field({
       "TIME.EPOCH:request.receive.time.epoch",
       "STRING:connection.client.user",
       "MICROSECONDS:server.process.time",
       "IP:connection.client.host",
       "HTTP.HEADER:request.header.true-client-ip",
       "VARIABLE:server.environment.unique_id",
       "HTTP.METHOD:request.firstline.method",
       "HTTP.URI:request.firstline.uri",
       "HTTP.PATH:request.firstline.uri.path",
       "HTTP.QUERYSTRING:request.firstline.uri.query",
       "STRING:request.firstline.uri.query.*",
       "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.*",
       "STRING:request.status.original",
       "HTTP.USERAGENT:request.user-agent",
       "HTTP.HEADER:request.header.host",
       "NUMBER:connection.client.logname",
       "BYTES:response.body.bytesclf",
       "HTTP.URI:request.referer",
       "HTTP.PATH:request.referer.path",
       "STRING:request.referer.query.*",
    })

    public void setValue(final String name, final String value) {
      System.out.println("Field: \"" + name + "\" = \"" + value + "\"");
    }
  }
```

and then I ran this code:

```
String logformat = "%t %u [%D %h %{True-Client-IP}i %{UNIQUE_ID}e %r] %{Cookie}i %s \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{host}i\" %l %b %{Referer}i";
String logline = "[02/Dec/2013:14:10:30 -0000] - [52075 10.102.4.254 177.43.52.210 UpyU1gpmBAwAACfd5W0AAAAW GET /SS14-VTam-ny_019.jpg.rendition.zoomable.jpg HTTP/1.1] hsfirstvisit=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fen-us||1372268254000; _opt_vi_3FNG8DZU=F870DCFD-CBA4-4B6E-BB58-4605A78EE71A; __ptca=145721067.0aDxsZlIuM48.1372279055.1379945057.1379950362.9; __ptv_62vY4e=0aDxsZlIuM48; __pti_62vY4e=0aDxsZlIuM48; __ptcz=145721067.1372279055.1.0.ptmcsr=(direct)|ptmcmd=(none)|ptmccn=(direct); __hstc=145721067.b86362bb7a1d257bfa2d1fb77e128a85.1372268254968.1379934256743.1379939561848.9; hubspotutk=b86362bb7a1d257bfa2d1fb77e128a85; USER_GROUP=julinho%3Afalse; has_js=1; WT_FPC=id=177.43.52.210-1491335248.30301337:lv=1385997780893:ss=1385997780893; dtCookie=1F2E0E1037589799D8D503EB8CFA12A1|_default|1; RM=julinho%3A5248423ad3fe062f06c54915e6cde5cb45147977; wcid=UpyKsQpmBAwAABURyNoAAAAS%3A35d8227ba1e8a9a9cebaaf8d019a74777c32b4c8; Carte::KerberosLexicon_getWGSN=82ae3dcd1b956288c3c86bdbed6ebcc0fd040e1e; UserData=Username%3AJULINHO%3AHomepage%3A1%3AReReg%3A0%3ATrialist%3A0%3ALanguage%3Aen%3ACcode%3Abr%3AForceReReg%3A0; UserID=1356673%3A12345%3A1234567890%3A123%3Accode%3Abr; USER_DATA=1356673%3Ajulinho%3AJulio+Jose%3Ada+Silva%3Ajulinho%40tecnoblu.com.br%3A0%3A1%3Aen%3Abr%3A%3AWGSN%3A1385990833.81925%3A82ae3dcd1b956288c3c86bdbed6ebcc0fd040e1e; MODE=FONTIS; SECTION=%2Fcontent%2Fsection%2Fhome.html; edge_auth=ip%3D177.43.52.210~expires%3D1385994522~access%3D%2Fapps%2F%2A%21%2Fbin%2F%2A%21%2Fcontent%2F%2A%21%2Fetc%2F%2A%21%2Fhome%2F%2A%21%2Flibs%2F%2A%21%2Freport%2F%2A%21%2Fsection%2F%2A%21%2Fwgsn%2F%2A~md5%3D90e73ee10161c1afacab12c6ea30b4ef; __utma=94539802.1793276213.1372268248.1385572390.1385990581.16; __utmb=94539802.52.9.1385991739764; __utmc=94539802; __utmz=94539802.1372268248.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); WT_FPC=id=177.43.52.210-1491335248.30301337:lv=1386000374581:ss=1386000374581; dtPC=-; NSC_wtfswfs_xfcgbsn40-41=ffffffff096e1a1d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; akamai-edge=5ac6e5b3d0bbe2ea771bb2916d8bab34ea222a6a 200 \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36\" \"www.domain.com\" - 463952 http://www.domain.com/content/report/shows/New_York/KSHK/trip/s_s_14_ny_ww/sheers.html";

Parser<MyRecord> parser = new ApacheHttpdLoglineParser<>(MyRecord.class, logformat);
MyRecord record = new MyRecord();

try {
  record = parser.parse(record, logline);
} catch (DisectionFailure disectionFailure) {
  disectionFailure.printStackTrace();
}
```

This output looks like this. Note that you can simply request the value of a specific cookie or 'all of them'.

```
Field: "STRING:connection.client.user" = "null"
Field: "MICROSECONDS:server.process.time" = "52075"
Field: "IP:connection.client.host" = "10.102.4.254"
Field: "HTTP.HEADER:request.header.true-client-ip" = "177.43.52.210"
Field: "VARIABLE:server.environment.unique_id" = "UpyU1gpmBAwAACfd5W0AAAAW"
Field: "STRING:request.status.original" = "200"
Field: "HTTP.USERAGENT:request.user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36"
Field: "HTTP.HEADER:request.header.host" = "www.domain.com"
Field: "NUMBER:connection.client.logname" = "null"
Field: "BYTES:response.body.bytesclf" = "463952"
Field: "HTTP.URI:request.referer" = "http://www.domain.com/content/report/shows/New_York/KSHK/trip/s_s_14_ny_ww/sheers.html"
Field: "HTTP.METHOD:request.firstline.method" = "GET"
Field: "HTTP.URI:request.firstline.uri" = "/SS14-VTam-ny_019.jpg.rendition.zoomable.jpg"
Field: "TIME.EPOCH:request.receive.time.epoch" = "1385993430000"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.hsfirstvisit" = "http://www.domain.com/en-us||1372268254000"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies._opt_vi_3fng8dzu" = "F870DCFD-CBA4-4B6E-BB58-4605A78EE71A"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__ptca" = "145721067.0aDxsZlIuM48.1372279055.1379945057.1379950362.9"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__ptv_62vy4e" = "0aDxsZlIuM48"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__pti_62vy4e" = "0aDxsZlIuM48"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__ptcz" = "145721067.1372279055.1.0.ptmcsr=(direct)|ptmcmd=(none)|ptmccn=(direct)"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__hstc" = "145721067.b86362bb7a1d257bfa2d1fb77e128a85.1372268254968.1379934256743.1379939561848.9"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.hubspotutk" = "b86362bb7a1d257bfa2d1fb77e128a85"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.user_group" = "julinho:false"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.has_js" = "1"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.wt_fpc" = "id=177.43.52.210-1491335248.30301337:lv=1385997780893:ss=1385997780893"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.dtcookie" = "1F2E0E1037589799D8D503EB8CFA12A1|_default|1"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.rm" = "julinho:5248423ad3fe062f06c54915e6cde5cb45147977"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.wcid" = "UpyKsQpmBAwAABURyNoAAAAS:35d8227ba1e8a9a9cebaaf8d019a74777c32b4c8"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.carte::kerberoslexicon_getwgsn" = "82ae3dcd1b956288c3c86bdbed6ebcc0fd040e1e"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.userdata" = "Username:JULINHO:Homepage:1:ReReg:0:Trialist:0:Language:en:Ccode:br:ForceReReg:0"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.userid" = "1356673:12345:1234567890:123:ccode:br"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.user_data" = "1356673:julinho:Julio Jose:da Silva:julinho@tecnoblu.com.br:0:1:en:br::WGSN:1385990833.81925:82ae3dcd1b956288c3c86bdbed6ebcc0fd040e1e"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.mode" = "FONTIS"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.section" = "/content/section/home.html"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.edge_auth" = "ip=177.43.52.210~expires=1385994522~access=/apps/*!/bin/*!/content/*!/etc/*!/home/*!/libs/*!/report/*!/section/*!/wgsn/*~md5=90e73ee10161c1afacab12c6ea30b4ef"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__utma" = "94539802.1793276213.1372268248.1385572390.1385990581.16"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__utmb" = "94539802.52.9.1385991739764"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__utmc" = "94539802"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.__utmz" = "94539802.1372268248.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.wt_fpc" = "id=177.43.52.210-1491335248.30301337:lv=1386000374581:ss=1386000374581"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.dtpc" = "-"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.nsc_wtfswfs_xfcgbsn40-41" = "ffffffff096e1a1d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660"
Field: "HTTP.COOKIE:request.cookies.akamai-edge" = "5ac6e5b3d0bbe2ea771bb2916d8bab34ea222a6a"
Field: "HTTP.PATH:request.referer.path" = "http://www.domain.com/content/report/shows/New_York/KSHK/trip/s_s_14_ny_ww/sheers.html"
Field: "HTTP.QUERYSTRING:request.firstline.uri.query" = ""
Field: "HTTP.PATH:request.firstline.uri.path" = "/SS14-VTam-ny_019.jpg.rendition.zoomable.jpg"
```