# java code to extract requests from access_log file to sql database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, access-log

How can I extract requests from access_log file to sql database (Oracle).
If I didn't ask the question correctly this is what the file looks like:

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:06:51 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate?rev1=1.3&rev2=1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4523
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:10:02 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/hsdivision HTTP/1.1" 200 6291
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:11:58 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WikiSyntax HTTP/1.1" 200 7352
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:20:55 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/DCCAndPostFix HTTP/1.1" 200 5253
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:23:12 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/oops/TWiki/AppendixFileSystem?template=oopsmore&param1=1.12&param2=1.12 HTTP/1.1" 200 11382
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:24:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/PeterThoeny HTTP/1.1" 200 4924
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:29:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Header_checks?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
```

My task is to get the IPs that accessed a specific file in the database.

So what I have to do is to extract with SQL using java to proccess/analyse the lines in this file and then I can get the IPs and other info from the sql table.

Can anyone help me with that? What I want exactly is the java code that analyses this log file to the sql database.

Sorry for my obvious lack of experience but this is new for me.

Comment: Sorry this question is too broad.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349184

Comment: One option could be to CREATE EXTERNAL table in Oracle that maps to the access_log file.From there you could use SQL to query for data.