# Patterns to identify type of data in a line of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse/extract data from a file of string format using Java. The file doesn't contain non-identical data, the data is delimited with comma in few lines, and with an empty space in few lines. But identical within the same line. Also, the parameters in the liens are non-identical.

Example of lines:

```
ipaadress,timestamp,text,text,url,text,email
email text ipaddress text timestamp url
text - timestamp ipaddress text text url email
text,integer,integer,text,ipaddress,timestamp email
```

and so on...

Say for example I have to identify email, ipaddress, email, url from all the lines, is there a pattern to do so? or should I just split by the delimiters and individually parse/identify if the split is an email/ipaddress/url and so on?

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349184/java-parse-log-file) to get it working for identical data using `Grok`, JSON is the take away. If there's a way out to solve the non-identical using `Grok`?

Help me understand.

Comment: If the order of fields is not same, then it is better to use one regex at a time to extract the information, although it can be done by single regex too but it will get a little complex.

Comment: Agree, split an then examine. A huge regex is way  harder to maintain and errorprone(there might be the super duper  regex genius out there for whom the regex solution is simpler but as you need to ask for it, it most definitely is like for most people ) .

Comment: Does this have *anything* to do with the 'grok' framework?  If not, you have tagged this incorrectly!  Please read the tag summaries before you add them to a question.

Comment: @StephenC  I have given a shot on parsing identical data with Grok in Java. Successfully extracted a JSON out of the lines. so I was curious if the non-identical could be put together.

Comment: 'grok' is a PHP framework.  What you are using is 'java-grok'.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not aware that Grok is a PHP framework, and I don't think it is. There are java example and git projects to use Grok with Java.

Comment: And the downvoter's, can you please let me know why and how this question is not useful?

Comment: If the accepted answer (basically "a sequence of regexs to split the lines") actually answers your question, then the question itself shows insufficient research effort.   That's the reason for my downvote.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok_(web_framework) ... actually it is Python.  (I was confusing Zope for Zend)  "java-grok" is a apparently a reimplementation of Grok for Java.  And certainly the "grok" tag is for the original Grok ... not the Java reimplementation.  Read the tag wiki!

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the information(wifki page). Yet I believe there should be a  way out to deal with this kind of data, instead if split and process. That's not the solution used in large sets of data though works for small data sets. If not how are people dealing with log analytics processing!! I'm actually looking/researching towards the best path.

Comment: By accepting that answer ... you have clearly indicated that what it says is a good enough answer for you.   On the other hand, there are only 8 questions in total tagged with both 'java' and 'grok' ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say for example I have to identify email, ipaddress, email, url from all the lines, is there a pattern to do so? or should I just split by the delimiters and individually parse/identify if the split is an email/ipaddress/url and so on?

I'd say definitely **first split** and **then identify** the different parts, this will take a way **a lot** of complexity. Lets say you want to create a Pattern to extract the email adress from one of these Strings, on top of the mere email pattern you also have to be carefull to match:

1. Adresses *at the start* of the line (will start with an letter, can end before a comma or whitespace)
2. Adresses *in between* (start/end /afterbefore a comma or whitespace)
3. Adress *at the end* of the line (start after a comma or whitespace can end with a new line depending how you ingest your input)

Finding a regex to match all of these cases (for each data type) will be way more work then just splitting the Strings(s) and identifying them separately.

You should also think about how to handle text data that contains white spaces and commas itself.