# count quotes in a string that do not have a backslash before them

Tags: ruby, regex

Hey I'm trying to use a regex to count the number of quotes in a string that are not preceded by a backslash..
for example the following string:

- `"\"Some text`
- `"\"Some \"text`

The code I have was previously using `String#count('"')`
obviously this is not good enough

When I count the quotes on both these examples I need the result only to be 1

I have been searching here for similar questions and ive tried using lookbehinds but cannot get them to work in ruby.

I have tried the following regexs on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352128/whats-the-regex-to-match-anything-except-a-double-quote-not-preceded-by-a-backsl)

- `/[^\\]"/`
- `^"((?<!\\)[^"]+)"`
- `^"([^"]|(?<!\)\\")"`

None of them give me the results im after

Maybe a regex is not the way to do that. Maybe a programatic approach is the solution

Comment: Ruby (until 1.8) doesn't support lookbehind, that's probably why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = subject.scan(
    /(?:        # match either
     ^         # start-of-string\/line
    |          # or
     \G        # the position where the previous match ended
    |          # or
     [^\\]     # one non-backslash character
    )          # then
    (\\\\)*    # match an even number of backslashes (0 is even, too)
    "          # match a quote/x)
```

gives you an array of all quote characters (possibly with a preceding non-quote character) except unescaped ones.

The `\G` anchor is needed to match successive quotes, and the `(\\\\)*` makes sure that backslashes are only counted as escaping characters if they occur in odd numbers before the quote (to take Amarghosh's correct caveat into account).

Comment: it returns an array of nils however the number of nils is the number of quotes so its perfect, thanks!

`'"\"foo\"bar"'.scan(/(?:^|\G|[^\\])(\\\\)*"/x).size => 2`

Answer (score 3):

How about `string.count('"') - string.count("\\"")`?

Comment: well i never thought of doing that, it works. I think that will do.
:)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how it can work, since `count("\\"")` counts the number of backslash plus the number of double quotes, each one taken independently. I thick something like `string.count('"') - string.scan(/\\"/).count` would better work.