# How to match a String of any characters (including special characters) except a colon not preceded by a backslash within a larger expression?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

*Disclaimer: I don't think this is a duplicate of [What's the regex to match anything except a double quote not preceded by a backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352128/whats-the-regex-to-match-anything-except-a-double-quote-not-preceded-by-a-backs), as the OA there has delimiting double quotes that s/he can use.*

I'm trying to match a single-line string in Java that takes the following form in pseudo code where `[any!=:]` is short for "*at least one of any characters except a colon without a preceding backslash*".

```
[any!=:]::[any!=:]:[any!=:]
```

I'm not good at regex, but I checked out *negative lookbehind* and have come up with (not Java, but regular regex):

```
[^(?<!\\):]+:{2}[^(?<!\\):]+:[^(?<!\\):]+
```

This does match something like

**(1)** `asd::asd:asd`

but does **not** match, e.g.,

**(2)** `asd\:asd::asd\:asd:ads\:asd` (which, however, it should).

Taking the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352140/731040) to the question linked above, I also tried the following.

```
([^(?<!\\):]|\\:)+:{2}([^(?<!\\):]|\\:)+:([^(?<!\\):]|\\:)+
```

This works for **(2)**, and for some but not all *special characters* (according to [RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/rdjg9)). The characters `[c]` it does work for when used in a combination of `[c]::[c]:[c]` are for example `$`, `"`, `%`, `&`, `/`, `+`. The ones it does **not** work for are, e.g., `?`, `!`, `)`, `\`.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax),

> The usual metacharacters are {}^$.|*+? and .

Why then does my regex work for some metacharacters (as they are apparently called), but not others? And how can I "fix" my regex to take into account those that don't work?

Comment: To match any character that except colons not preceded by a backslash, I used [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/hP8sG2/1)

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight that won't work if a string starts with `\:` (not sure if this is required by OP).

Comment: @Sam Well.... I'm at a loss then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this:

```
(?:\\:|[^:])+:{2}(?:\\:|[^:])+:(?:\\:|[^:])+
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dO1tO8/1) (I used `^` and `$` anchors for demonstration purposes)

---

The only part that needs explanation is the logic for "any character except a colon (unless preceded by a backslash)": `(?:\\:|[^:])+`.  Let's break that down:

```
(?:       # start non-capturing group
  \\      # match \ literally
  :       # match : literally
 |        # OR
  [^:]    # match anything but :
)+        # repeat non-capturing group 1+ times
```

Pretty much we look for one character at a time (in a non-capturing group) and repeat this logic 1+ times.  This character can either be `\:` or anything BUT `:` (`[^:]`).  Note that the `\\:` has to be the first piece of your alternation, otherwise `[^:]` will match the backslash which may be necessary to escape a colon.

---

**Update:**  *Why doesn't `([^(?<!\\):]|\\:)+` work?*

To put it simply, lookarounds don't do anything in character classes.  So let's break this one down:

```
(             # start capturing group
  [^(?<!\\):] # match anything but (, <, !, \, or :
 |            # OR
  \\          # match \ literally
  :           # match : literally
)+            # repeat capturing group 1+ times
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, and mighty quick at that! What I don't get though is why my half-baked solution does work for some but not all of the metacharacters... (Note to myself: Need to understand non-capturing groups).

Comment: Having it put simply before me did the trick :). I get it now.

Comment: Glad I could help :) thanks for the accepted answer -- carry on your regex way.