# Javascript regex get content inside of double quots

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I get content inside two strings?

Example:

Main string:

```
document.cookie="cookie=name";
```

How do I select the cookie=name part?

I tried this:

```
document.cookie=\"(.*?)\";
```

But this select the hole string not the cookie=name.

Comment: Your regex seems to do fine. You just need to [extract the first group from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352128/whats-the-regex-to-match-anything-except-a-double-quote-not-preceded-by-a-backs

Comment: `"\"cookie=name\"".match(/\"(.*?)\"/)[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
str.split('"')[1]
```

Comment: This will do it

Comment: Only if the value to be extracted does not contain any escaped double quotes

Comment: that would be the incentive to use a regex

Answer (score 1):

You have it, just extract the first match

```
var regex = /document.cookie=\"(.*?)\";/;
var match = regex.exec('document.cookie="cookie=name";');
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'document.cookie="cookie=name"';
let regx = /\".+=.+\"$/;

let match = str.match(regx)[0].replace(/\"/g, "");
console.log(match);

let [data, name] = match.split("=");
console.log("Data: " + data + " and name: " + name);
```

While splitting the string on a double quote is certainly efficient, the OP composed the post in a way that expresses interest in using a regex, a point this answer addresses. You may isolate the portion you wish to extract from the outer string with a regex that matches a pattern located at the end of `str`. Next, the string uses its replace method to globally replace all its double quotes. Then, the overall result is assigned to variable `match`, At this point, one now has extracted the inner string 'cookie=name'.

Of course, you may manipulate `match` by  splitting its string value on the equals character as this code does in a statement that employs array destructuring. This action  results in variables `data` and `name` respectively containing the values "cookie" and "name".