# regex to match anything except an unescaped quote

Tags: regex

I would be using kotlin regex engine.

There are a lot of other questions posted about matching unescaped quotes, but I'm struggling to implement my specific case.

Some example text:

```
"the Five Aggregates (from Sanskrit \"skandha\") (Buddhism)"
```

I want to match the whole pattern with something like

```
\"[^"]*\"
```

where `[^"]` is anything that isn't a `"`, however this is also matching the `\"` so I'm getting matches of

```
"the Five Aggregates (from Sanskrit \"
```

and

```
\") (Buddhism)"
```

So essentially I want to match `"[^unescapedquote]*"`

I tried to use an answer from a previous post like `"[^(?!<\\)"*]"`
But this didn't give me any matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What is the logic behind you marking this post as a duplicate of [What's the regex to match anything except a double quote not preceded by a backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352128/whats-the-regex-to-match-anything-except-a-double-quote-not-preceded-by-a-backs) ? The two answers there are erroneous and every single comment on that page suggest a lack of unferstanding of the solution to this question! So the post is 12 years old, and its really no wonder. Given this topic has hundreds of this question posed, is this the best one for a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that is escaped has to be matched with an escape that is not itself
escaped.

`(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\`some Character here

Furthermore, since escapes can be escaped, you have to match anything that
is escaped inside the quotes.

To that end, it is basically this form:

`(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\S\s][^\\"]*)*"`

see https://regex101.com/r/LRgBlQ/1

Note that the beginning part `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*` can be ommited if you
are taking care of (incorporating) the pre-quote part with another sub-expression.

---

```
 (?<! \\ )                  # Not an escape behind
 (?: \\\\ )*                # Optional even escapes
 "                          # Open quote
 [^\\"]*                    # Not an escape nor double quote
 (?:
      \\ [\S\s] [^\\"]*     # Escape anything then more not escaped, etc ...
 )*
 "                          # Close quote
```

Answer (score 0):

`((?<!\\)".*(?<!\\)")` will work for you. [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T1qGWX/2/)